# Was Jesus a vampire in Midnight Mass?

Tags: midnight-mass-2021

In *Midnight Mass*, Monsignor Pruitt believes the winged vampire to be an angel, but he *explicitly* draws a link between the Eucharist, based in Jesus's line "whoso eateth my flesh, and drinketh my blood, hath eternal life; and I will raise him up at the last day," and the changes worked by the consumption of the ancient vampire's blood.

Further, Pruitt found the vampire in an ancient cave within walking distance of Jerusalem, suggesting the presence of vampires in ancient Israel around the time that, as the Biblical account would have it, Jesus performed similar miraculous healings and resurrections to those Pruitt and his vampire ally carried out on the show.

Is Jesus of Nazareth implied to be a vampire within the setting of *Midnight Mass*, or even perhaps the same ancient vampire that appears in the show?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly the implication. And that implication is based on all the evidence you've highlighted in your question.

Comment: @Valorum I respectfully disagree. Pruitt and Bev has assumed that the vampire is an angel and matched the fragments from the Bible to confirm their beliefs.

Comment: @Yasskier - The question is not about whether the winged vampire was an angel, which it clearly was not, but whether Jesus of Nazareth was a vampire (whether the one on show or a different one). If there were vampires around in Roman Palestine while an itinerant preacher was alleged to have performed miraculous healings much like those on the show and was promoting a ritual that, taken literally, is exactly what is needed to use vampiric blood in precisely that way, it's reasonable to ask whether there is a connection.

Comment: @Adamant - No, that is impossible since vampires from Midnight Mass catch fire in sunlight.  Jesus has been seen many times during the day and was definitely crucified during one.

Comment: @Yasskier - The idea would be, presumably, that either the stories were distorted over time (time of day is an easy thing to get wrong), or that Jesus was precisely a not-yet-fully-transformed vampire, as Monsignor Pruitt was initially (until, you know, he rose from the dead...hmm, that sounds familiar). If the winged vampire is the "end stage" of the ordinary human vampires (something that is far from clear), it could be even *be* Jesus.

Comment: @Adamant I got you, but... the movie is not about whether a certain historical/religious figure was a vampire or not. It is about faith and religion. For example, Father Paul shouldn't add anything to the communion wine even if it was given to him by Jesus personally and yet he is corrupting the holiest for Catholics ritual.  Immortal vampires drinking blood exist far before this movie, yet they don't suggest that Jesus was one of them - their blood is a corrupted parody of the communion.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I've decided to rewrite my previous answer</sup>

Let me try to get to the original question from different points of view:

### Do characters in the *Midnight Mass* think that Jesus was a vampire (because the "angel's blood" heals like described in the Gospels)?

No. Neither Monsignore Pruit/Father Paul nor Bev Keane makes that connection. There is the "angel's" blood and the blood of Jesus (as described in the Gospels), the former heals the body, and the latter heals the soul. Nowhere no one suggests that Jesus would be the same as this angel.

### Could Jesus be a vampire? There are references to blood in the Gospels!

No. While there are obvious references to blood during the Last Supper (and are the critical part of the Christian mass)

> Whoever eats my flesh and drinks my blood has eternal life, and I will raise them up at the last day. (John 6:54)

There are also numerous references to Jesus appearing in the daylight (Sermon on the Mount, entrance to Jerusalem, and finally the crucifixion itself), while the vampires from the movie are immediately immolated in the daylight.

### But the Gospels (at least in the movie) could be wrong!

Well, yes, because we know that there are vampires in the world of *Midnight Mass*, it is a certain possibility. But we could say the same about any person that was living at some stage near Jerusalem.

### But does the movie suggest that Jesus could be a vampire?

I wouldn't go anywhere near such a suggestion. Yes, we have a Catholic priest uncovering a "benevolent" vampiric creature near Jerusalem whose blood can be used in healing, just like the previously mentioned blood of Jesus. But the similarity between vampires living thanks to blood and Christians living (well, in the afterlife) thanks to Jesus's blood is a common theme, almost as old as this particular religion. There is a great thesis called ["The Vampire myth and Christianity](https://scholarship.rollins.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1015&context=mls)" that explores it in detail or an interesting article "[Are vampires Jesus evil twins?](https://www.christiancentury.org/article/2010-11/eat-my-flesh-drink-my-blood-are-vampires-jesus-evil-twins)" (and probably dozen others) that explores this theme.

### But the vampire was hiding near Jerusalem!

So? We don't know how old the creature is - it could be much younger or much older than Christianity. And please notice, that well before Jesus in that area there were religions (including Judaism) that were using blood, including human ones.

### But could we explain the miracles from the Gospel as performed using vampiric blood?

Well, maaaybe. We could imagine Jesus walking with a bottle of vampiric blood and administering it to the sick. Possible, but it seems that unless the target is fully transformed into a vampire, you need quite a lot of vampiric blood to perform the healing. Still, it is not improbable.

### So is there any connection between Jesus and the "angel"?

In my opinion...yes, but not the one as described in the OP. Monsignore Pruit have found the vampire in the desert and has sworn fealty to it. Where Jesus comes here? Well, in the "Temptation of the Christ". In short, Jesus is wandering the desert and meets the Devil, who offers him the whole world, if Jesus bows to him. According to the Gospels, Jesus refused, Ms Pruit did not.

Comment: So your argument here is that the vampire is the inspiration for the Devil, and that Jesus met it in the desert? Or do you simply think there is a metaphorical similarity?

Comment: @Adamant To be honest, I'm not sure. There is a definite similarity between those stories and you could see the whole series as a sort of devil work to twist both good Christians (Pruit/Paul) and the bad ones (Bev)